# PYTHON WTForms flask - saving data from drop down list to database

Tags: python, database

New to python and flask.

Trying to save data from drop down list to database using WTForms.

### The aim is to get the data from table
**Choice(db.model)**.

upload it to each field to choose from ->
**Choice(FlaskForm)**

And store chosen data in **Order(db.model)**

I did managet to understand how to get three drop down lists. But I am missing the point how to save chosen data to **Order table**

```
   form = ChoiceForm(csrf_enabled=True)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        ''' get instance of version from form data'''
        item = Order(
                    form.x1.data,
                    form.opts.data,
                    form.xx.data,
                    )

        db.session.add(item)
        db.session.commit()
```

This code above is the part I need tu figure out (how to commit the data to database order)

Below is the code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms_sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = "Secret Key"
 
#SqlAlchemy Database Configuration With Mysql
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///leodat1.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Choice(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    extra = db.Column(db.String(50))

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Choice {}'.format(self.name)

    def __init__(self, name, extra):
        self.name = name 
        self.extra = extra

def choice_query():
    return Choice.query
def choice_query_x():
    return Choice.query
def choice_query_x1():
    return Choice.query




class ChoiceForm(FlaskForm):
    opts = QuerySelectField(query_factory=choice_query, allow_blank=False, get_label='extra')
    xx = QuerySelectField(query_factory=choice_query_x, allow_blank=False, get_label='extra')
    x1 = QuerySelectField(query_factory=choice_query_x1, allow_blank=False, get_label='extra')


class Order(db.Model):
    order_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_01 = db.Column(db.String(50))
    item_02 = db.Column(db.String(50))
    choice_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('choice.id'))
    Choice = db.relationship('Choice', foreign_keys=[choice_id])


    def __init__(self, order_id, item_01, item_02):
        self.order_id = order_id 
        self.item_01 = item_01
        self.item_02 = item_02

        ''' I can not get it how can I save data from drop down list'''
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = ChoiceForm(csrf_enabled=True)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        ''' get instance of version from form data'''
        item = Order(
                    form.x1.data,
                    form.opts.data,
                    form.xx.data,
                    )

        db.session.add(item)
        db.session.commit()


        return render_template('result.html',form=form)

    return render_template('index.html',form=form)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def result():

    return render_template('result.html', form = form, xx = xx, x1 = x1)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this statement:

```
item = Order(
                    form.x1.data,
                    form.opts.data,
                    form.xx.data,
                    )
```

Try changing it to

```
item = Order( var1 = form.x1.data, var2 = form.opts.data, var3 = form.xx.data)
```

where var1, var2 and var3 are the column names for the Order table.